# tortoise svn+ssh constant login

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I'm trying to connect to a remote repo using svn+ssh through Tortoise. I can connect via svn+ssh:// through the command line no problem from other remote servers. However, on my windows box, I'm getting this constant cycle of prompts for username and then password. If I have the patience and go through like 30 of these, I can actually see the repo! But why the heck is it not just storing the username and password and be done with it?

I'm seeing a number of tutorials that require configurations on the server side, but this can't be right: I should just be able to tell Tortoise to remember my username and password, enter it once, and it's now stored with that working copy, right? I've looked through the TortoiseSVN settings, and under Advanced I see "AllowAuthSave" and it's set to "true" so I'm figuring this is what it's supposed to be. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [RTFM](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) me! By appending my server's username to the URL, it solved 90% of the login requests. Still asked me for my pwd twice during a repo checkout, but that's definitely within operational parameters.

```
svn+ssh://yourserverusername@serveraddress.com/var/svn/reponame/trunk
```